# How to calculate Time difference based on conditions i.e different strings and new date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to solve this problem but I cannot think of a formula to do in Excel.

| Date | Time | Photographer | TimeWorked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:17:00 AM | alizée16 | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:23:00 AM | alondra | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 4:38:00 PM | alondra | 21 |
| 04/09/2021 | 7:17:00 PM | alondra | 54 |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:21:00 AM | aman | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:22:00 AM | aman | 1 |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:58:00 AM | aman | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:38:00 AM | amelia | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:43:00 AM | amelia | 5 |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:47:00 AM | amelia | 4 |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:54:00 AM | amelia | 7 |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:55:00 AM | amelia | 1 |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:57:00 AM | amelia | 2 |
| 04/09/2021 | 7:12:00 AM | amelia | 15 |
| 04/09/2021 | 7:15:00 AM | amelia | 3 |
| 04/09/2021 | 7:20:00 AM | amelia | 5 |
| 04/09/2021 | 7:28:00 AM | amelia | 8 |
| 04/09/2021 | 9:45:00 AM | amelia | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:44:00 AM | amelia | 59 |
| 12/09/2021 | 7:33:00 AM | amelia | 5 |
| 12/09/2021 | 8:16:00 AM | amelia | 43 |
| 12/09/2021 | 8:22:00 AM | amelia | 6 |
| 12/09/2021 | 8:25:00 AM | amelia | 3 |

I want to calculate TimeWorked in minutes which is calculated by b3-b2, b4-b3,b5-b4 and so on. I have currently used MINUTE(b3-b2) formula.

But desired result is not so simple. I want to differentiate it on the basis of date and photographer as well i.e If the date or photographer or both changes, then I again want to start from 0.

e.g in cell 1 since the 04/09/2021 is a new date, I want TimeWorked to start from 0.
In cell 3 the photographer changes so I want the calculation start again from 0(instead of current value 21).

In cell 21, the date changes from 04/09 to 12/09 so time worked again starts from 0.

I would have done it manually but the table contains 13K rows so doing it manually will take a lot of time.

If it doesn't work in Excel, we can do it in Python or SQL as well and export it back as csv but I a newbie in both so I will need help with Python and SQL code as well.

Comment: Are you asking for a solution in SQL, or Excel here? You've tagged both. Excel and SQL Server are very different, and work very differently.

Comment: If you *are* asking for a solution on how to write an Excel Formula, you're on the wrong site; you want [su] (as mentioned in the [[tag:excel]] excerpt).

Comment: @Larnu Thanks I will try posting it there but I cannot post images there for now

Comment: You likely shouldn't be anyway; use markdown tables. Images of text is almost always poorly received across the sites in the community.

Comment: @Larnu It is acceptable to post Excel Formula questions here.  That is a topic that has been discussed in detail on meta and it has been determined that excel formula is a form of programming.

Comment: *If* that is the case, @ScottCraner , then the excerpt is incorrect: *"General help regarding Excel for single worksheet functions is available at Super User (http://superuser.com/)."*

Comment: I cannot speak to that description, but here is one such meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic

Comment: Also in the first sentence it states `or complex formula development` @Larnu  This is not a "single" formula situation.  It will require the nesting and use of mutliple formula and as such would fall into the `complex` category.

Comment: @DhirajD can you explain what you would expect with lines 6 and 7  They are both the same day and same Photographer, but the time on 7 is before that of line 6.  Should we do the absolute, or is this a sorting error?  Time cannot be negative in Excel.

Comment: I feel I have a different opinion on what "complex" is to you, @ScottCraner .

Comment: As however, the OP han't responded about the solution type they want, I'm going to go ahead and remove some of these tags.

Comment: @ScottCraner It might be due to sorting error.

Comment: Can you then give a true example of the data as it should be sorted?  And as @Larnu stated as a markdown table and not a photo so we can copy paste the data?

Comment: @Larnu As I said I need to calculate time difference in minutes. But if the date or photographer changes then we need to set TimeWorked for that row to 0 and again start calculations from there. Hope this solves the doubt. I am still a newbie so I am not known to complex formulas. I think we may need OR function. e.g if Date Or photographer changes then set TimeWorked to 0.

Comment: And as I asked, @DhirajD, did you want this solution in SQL or Excel? You tagged both. I removed the former's related tags.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have posted it in superuser using Markdown table https://superuser.com/questions/1677428/how-to-calculate-time-difference-based-on-conditions-i-e-different-strings-and-n

Comment: Please then remove this question from this site.  Posting in both is not proper.

Comment: @Larnu If the problem gets complex in Excel then maybe we can solve it in SQL and then export the data into Excel again. That is why I used SQL tag.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?  In TimeWorked it will calculate the number of minutes between it both the date and the photographer is the same.  That means if one of the following applies, it will be 0:

- First entry for the photographer for the day (includes change of date)
- Photographer changes.

[image: Example Table]

If so, assuming your data is in columns A to D and your header is on row 1, the following will give you the answer you seek:

**Important - sort your data by date, then photographer first**

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1,C2=C1),(B2-B1)*24*60,0)
```

The AND is checking if the date and photographer are the same. If they are it calculates the difference.  We multiple by 24 to get hours and then by 60 to get minutes.  If you don't multiple you just get a fraction of a day.